# Almost all my rep is gone on Stack Overflow, and my profile seems unlinked (no name)

Tags: bug

Hours ago I was over 2700 rep on stackoverflow - now I am at 31

On stackoverflow I am user2229687

Comment: This is an ongoing bug I'm afraid (I'll just find the link), don't worry, this is stack exchange's fault not yours

Comment: Consider this a "free rep card" here on Meta - hope it will be resolved soon! :)

Comment: Yes, as Richard said, this looks like you're being hit with the same bug as a few other users. Your [reputation timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963099/user2229687?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=1) looks normal, so your total should go back to normal after some time as well.

Comment: Thanks for reporting - we are aware of the bug, but it is subtle, and the more examples we see, the easier it will be to find and fix.

Comment: @Oded looks like the reset is triggered by a downvote, see his reputation tab.

Comment: @Glenn I fear you'll have to change your display name manually, you can do that now regardless of the rep issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That’s a powerful downvote; 30k privilege - nuclear downvote

Comment: ...and rep is back. :)

Comment: Posting an answer fixed it as suggested.  Can I has pirate hat back?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, a dv seems to trigger the bug, but the exact conditions are not entirely clear.

Comment: If it helps, the "nuclear" downvote is not showing now under today's rep on my profile rep list

Comment: Cheers @Glenn glad it was sorted out! As for the "post answer to fix it", not 100% sure it's correct hence I edited my comment above. Anyway, I can see the downvote [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xMdt2.png). Last but not least, hats are no more, it's nothing personal unlike that rep eating worm. :)

Comment: I meant hats for the victims of the bug ;)  that downvote was before the bug, there was a second downvote that is now missing for my "fast poker hand" answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889147/fast-poker-hand-ranking/19944092#19944092

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you find that downvote - it might be related to what caused the bug

Comment: @Glenn the downvote was cast today on [this answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20962875/447356) - since you also got upvote later, it's now with score of 0. Click the 0 to see the split of +1/-1. As for compensation, I think badge would be more appropriate! ;-) (and you might soon get bronze badge here on Meta for this very report :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard -- but I saw a downvote for the other post mentioned after the bug manifested, now (after "restore") there is no trace of it (answer shows 0 up/0 down) -- if somebody can look into it, it seems more likely to be related.  As I had rep for quite a while after the downvote you are looking at, that seems less likely.

Comment: @Glenn what other post? It might be simply someone who undid his vote, when it's done in the same day there's no record of this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://stackoverflow.com/a/19944092/2963099 -- when looking for symptoms of a bug - I rarely believe in coincidence

Comment: @Glenn what makes you think it was ever downvoted? Where did you see the downvote and when? Anyway, this one does look like coincidence, even if someone indeed downvoted then changed his mind during the 5 minutes window.

Comment: @ShadowWizard after I logged in this morning and saw my rep was 31, I looked at my profile rep tab and saw it down the list abit, (pretty sure I also saw it more than 5 minutes later as well) so more than 5 minutes likely elapsed.   I thought that was the downvote you all were mentioning

Comment: Dunno... if a dev is reading those comments he might take a look.